# PHP inheritance, overriding methods in subclasses, passing values between classes

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, overriding

I have the following class structure. Base class Car with first subclass NewCar and second subclass InsuranceCar, both override method value from its base class.
Both subclasses contain overriden method value, which uses protected field $price from Car. Price is then used in subclass NewCar in overridden value method, and in InsuranceClass more or less the same way.
Overridden method value in subclass NewCar applies calculation formulas to count the price of the new NewCar object. Overriden method value in InsuranceCar is similar, it also takes price to calculate final price taking car age condition to decrement the price. What I see here is, that method value in InsuranceCar takes as input price field from NewCar object, not from new InsuranceCar object. How to use price value set in constructor by creating new object of InsuranceCar, not the value that was calulated in NewCar?

```
<?php
class Car{
    static $qty = 5;
    private $model;
    protected $price;
    private $course;
    public function __construct($model, $price, $course)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->price = $price;
        $this->course = $course;
    }
    public static function getQty()
    {
        return self::$qty;
    }
    public static function setQty($qty)
    {
        self::$qty = $qty;
    }
    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }
    public function setModel($model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
    public function getCourse()
    {
        return $this->course;
    }
    public function setCourse($course)
    {
        $this->course = $course;
    }
    function value(){
        return $this->getPrice() * $this->getCourse() * Car::$qty;

    }
    public function __toString() {
        return "Model ". $this->model ." Price ".$this->price ." Course ".$this->course;
    }
}
class NewCar extends Car{
    private $alarm = false;
    private $radio = false;
    private $climatronic = false;
    public function __construct($model, $price, $course, $alarm, $radio, $climatronic)
    {
        parent::__construct($model, $price, $course);
        $this->alarm = $alarm;
        $this->radio = $radio;
        $this->climatronic = $climatronic;

    }
    public function isAlarm()
    {
        return $this->alarm;
    }
    public function setAlarm($alarm)
    {
        $this->alarm = $alarm;
    }
    public function isRadio()
    {
        return $this->radio;
    }
    public function setRadio($radio)
    {
        $this->radio = $radio;
    }
    public function isClimatronic()
    {
        return $this->climatronic;
    }
    public function setClimatronic($climatronic)
    {
        $this->climatronic = $climatronic;
    }
    public function value()
    {
        parent::value();
        if($this->alarm=="true"){$this->setPrice($this->getPrice() * 1.05);}
        if($this->radio=="true"){$this->setPrice($this->getPrice() * 1.075 );}
        if($this->climatronic=="true"){$this->setPrice($this->getPrice() * 1.10 );}

    }
    public function __toString() {
        return "  Model ". $this->getModel() ." Price ".$this->getPrice() ." Course ".$this->getCourse().
            " Has alarm " .$this->alarm ." Has radio ". $this->radio .
            " Has climatronic ". $this->climatronic;

    }
}
class InsuranceCar extends NewCar {
    private $firstOwner = false;
    private $years = 0;
    public function __construct($model, $price, $course, $alarm, $radio, $climatronic, $firstOwner, $years)
    {
        parent::__construct($model, $price, $course, $alarm, $radio, $climatronic);
        $this->firstOwner = $firstOwner;
        $this->years = $years;
    }
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }
    public function isFirstOwner()
    {
        return $this->firstOwner;
    }
    public function setFirstOwner($firstOwner)
    {
        $this->firstOwner = $firstOwner;
    }
    public function getYears()
    {
        return $this->years;
    }
    public function setYears($years)
    {
        $this->years = $years;
    }
    public function value()
    {
        parent::value();
        if($this->firstOwner=="true")
        {$this->setPrice($this->getPrice() * 0.95 );}
        $this->setPrice(($this->getPrice()) * (1 - (($this->getYears()) / 100)));
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return "  Model ". $this->getModel() ." Price ".$this->getPrice() ." Course ".$this->getCourse().
            " Has alarm " . $this->isAlarm() ." Has radio ". $this->isRadio() .
            " Has climatronic ". $this->isClimatronic() . " Is first owner " . $this->firstOwner .
            " How old " . $this->years;
    }
}
$c1 = new Car("mercedes", 31, 4.5);
$nc1 = new NewCar("mercedes", 30, 5, "true", "true", "false" );
$nc1->value(). "\n";
echo $nc1 . "\n";
echo "Value NewCar " . $nc1->getPrice() * $nc1->getCourse() * Car::$qty. "\n";
$ic = new InsuranceCar("bmw", 30, 5, "true", "true", "false", "false", 5);
$ic->value(). "\n";
echo $ic. "\n";
echo "Value InsuranceCar " . $ic->getPrice() * $ic->getCourse() * Car::$qty. "\n";
?>
```

Comment: That's not valid code, and it's very hard to understand what's what, and thus to guess what visibility (public, private, protected) you have in mind for those methods. Please, edit your question to add properly formatted (and syntactically valid) code.

Comment: `private $A` in class A is invisible to subclasses!

Comment: Do you have any specific question about the given code? Can you reduce it to the minimal parts needed such that others can understand it quicker?